# Printing accented characters from a Java program onto a linux shell

Tags: java, shell, non-ascii-characters

I'm running a Java program from command line in Ubuntu, and trying to print accented characters onto the console. But the characters get displayed as `?` on the console. How do I make the shell display accented characters that are output from the program?

Answer (score 1):

Set the LANG environment variable in your shell:

```
LANG=en_EN.utf-8
```

See also the ubunutu docs on [environment variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables).

Comment: Still the character gets printed as ?